# JsonDeserialize single variables from nested object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, graphql

**Using Java, Spring Boot.**

I'm making a RestTemplate call (against GraphQL) that returns a JSON.

The JSON Response

```
{
  "customer_name": "Jon Doe",
  "address": {
    "address_id": 4 
  }
}
```

I want to deserialize the nested addressId into the Customer Pojo. Here is my current approach:

```
public class Customer implements Serializable {

  @JsonProperty("customer_name")
  private String customerName;

  @JsonDeserialize(using = IdFromAddressDeserializer.class)
  @JsonProperty("address")
  private Integer addressId;

  public Integer getAddressId() { return this.addressId; }
  public void setAddressId(Integer addressId) { this.addressId = addressId; }
```

```
public class IdFromAddressDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Integer> {

  @Override
  public Integer deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        
        // ISSUE p.getText.toString() -> "{"
        // I would expect that I can parse the json for address and extract the id field from the map

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you find this helps? Create a method inside Customer.java and remove the annotation jsonDeserialize and add ignore unknown properties to true. `@JsonProperty("address") private void extractNested(Map<String,Object> address) { this.addressId = (Integer)address.get("address_id"); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JsonDeserialize-Annotation seems to be wrong. Maybe we have other Versions, but i need a "using=" to get it compiled:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using=IdFromAddressDeserializer.class)
```

To get the complete String at once from the JsonParser, you can use...

```
@Override
public Integer deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

    Sting myJsonStr = parser.readValueAsTree().toString();

    return 0;
}
```

But consider to let the parser do the work ... so you don't have to parse the string by yourself :-) . E.g.

```
@Override
public Integer deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

    while (parser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
        if ("address_id".equals(parser.getCurrentName())) {
            parser.nextToken();
            return parser.getIntValue();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If do something like this it should work by itself, without all the annotations. Also you have misspelled address as adresss with three s's

```
restTemplate.getForObject(
        HOST,
        Customer.class,
        Map.of("key", value)
```